# matrixflip(m,d) where m is the matrix and d can be either h or v which are horizontal and vertical respectively

Tags: matrix, flip

I am trying to write a python code for function which should return the matrix flipped horizontally and vertically

Am new to python

def matrixflip(myl,'v'):
    output = list(myl[::-1])
    return output

> > > myl = [[1,2],[3,4]]
> > >
> > > myl
> > >       [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
> > >
> > > matrixflip(myl,'h')
> > >       [[2, 1], [4, 3]]
> > >
> > > myl
> > >       [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
> > >
> > > matrixflip(myl,'v')
> > >       [[3, 4], [1, 2]]
> > >
> > > myl
> > >       [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
def matrixflip(l,char):
    myl = copy.deepcopy(l)
    if char == 'h':
        for i in range(len(myll)):
            myl[i].reverse()
    if char == 'v':
        i,j = 0, len(myl)-1
        while(i<j):
            myl[i], myl[j] = myl[j], myl[i]
            i+=1
            j-=1
    return(myl)
```

Copy is used because original matrix value changed.
So don't change original list.